Increasing Docker post_max_size and upload_max_filesize caused "given data was invalid" error in Laravel
This shouldn't be as difficult as it's becoming and I'm ashamed of asking for help, but it could be happening to someone else, so here it goes:
My initial problem was trying to upload a 54Mb txt file with Laravel and I was getting PostTooLargeExcpetion in this line:
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt',
    ]);

During Wamp times, modifying post_max_size and upload_max_filesize was easy but now took me a while to find that it should be done with something like this
RUN echo 'post_max_size = 64M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-post-max-size.ini
RUN echo 'upload_max_filesize = 64M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-upload-max-filesize.ini

Now the error stopped being thrown but no error was shown at all. By using xdebug I found that an error was being thrown (but not shown, idk why) and it was "given data was invalid".
I thought it was because both post and upload were initially equal, due to this restriction and increased upload to 100. But the error persisted.
RUN echo 'post_max_size = 64M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-post-max-size.ini
RUN echo 'upload_max_filesize = 100M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-upload-max-filesize.ini

Now I'm out of ideas. Why is this error being thrown? Is it fixable?
[Update:]
upload.blade.php
<div class="flex-center position-ref">
    <form action="{{ route('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Select the file to reorder the columns</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control-file">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>

FileUploadController.php
public function showUploadForm()
    {
        return view('upload');
    }

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        //Log::info($request->file('file')->getClientMimeType());
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt',
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('file');

        // Process the file
        $processedData = $this->processFile($file);

        // Generate a new file name
        $newFileName = 'reordered_' .  $file->getClientOriginalName() . '_'.time().' . '.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // Write processed data into a new file
        $handle = fopen(storage_path('app/processed/' . $newFileName), 'w');
        foreach ($processedData as $rowData) {
            //fputcsv($handle, $rowData, "\t");
            fputs($handle, implode("\t", $rowData)."\n");
        }
        fclose($handle);

        // Return a link to the processed file
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/processed/' . $newFileName))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }

    private function processFile($file)
    {
        $data = [];
        $isHeader = true;

        // Read the CSV file
        if (($handle = fopen($file->getRealPath(), 'r')) !== false) {
            while (($rowData = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "\t")) !== false) {
                if ($isHeader) {
                    // Check if we reached the [Data] section
                    if ($rowData[0] === '[Data]') {
                        $isHeader = false;
                    }
                    // If still in the header section, simply push the row to data as is
                    //$data[] = $rowData;
                } else {
                    $merged = $rowData[4] == 'Chr' ? 'Plus Strand' : $rowData[8].$rowData[9];

                    // Swap columns as required
                    $processedRow = [
                        $rowData[2], // SNP Name
                        $rowData[4], // Chr
                        $rowData[5], // Position
                        $merged
                    ];

                    $data[] = $processedRow;
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

        return $data;
    }


"The given data was invalid" looks to be a validation error, so your file is being uploaded, it's just not being registered as a txt or csv file.  You might want to try Log::info($request->file('file')->getClientMimeType()); (or might be getMimeType()) before the validation and check your log file to see what it contains.

That's a good catch @aynber. The returned type was application/octet-stream. But I removed the mime validation and still fails with the same error. Also, if I remove some rows, the app does not fail.

BTW Even if I completely remove the validator line, the file is detected as zero-sized

Can you show how you're uploading the file? It shouldn't be octet-stream

Sure. Just added them as edit to the post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737830/uploading-a-large-file-in-laravel-8-returns-an-empty-file-with-application-octet suggests it's still the size setting. Try larger than 100M for both.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594854/why-does-laravels-getmimetype-method-identify-a-file-as-application-octet-st also suggests it can't detect the file type, possibly because of something else.

How much RAM does your server have?

@JosePalazuelos: Docker says I'm using 201.21MB / 3.75GB Memory and 0.71% / 400% (4 cores allocated) CPU

@aynber I increased to 100MB and 250MB and restarted the containers, but the error seems to persist.

Ok, here's the thing. And is as stupid as it sounded:
I made the changes in the Dockerfile, the first time and I rebuilt and that's why the error disappeared, but the first time I only added the post_max_size line and not the upload_max_filesize and I remembered it was required too, so I edited the Dockerfile with that line but, this time I only ran docker-compose down and up, cause ChatGPT told me so (foolish me).
Long story short: @JosePalazuelos pointed out that I should check phpinfo and it was there when I noticed that post was 64MB but upload only 2MB.
Summary:

Check phpinfo
Make sure to rebuild and not only restart

